# Give necessary and sufficient conditions that every function in the weak* closure of a linear subspace of $X^*$ is the weak* limit of a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. If $M$ is a linear subspace in $X^*$, give necessary and sufficient conditions that every functional in the weak* closure of $M$ be the weak* limit of a sequence from $M$.

My professor said this theorem was relevant for this problem:

**Theorem:**
If $X$ is a separable Banach space and $M$ is a linear subspace in $X^*$, the following statements are equivalent:

1. $M$ is weak* sequentially dense in $X^*$.
2. There is a positive constant $c$ such that for every $x \in X$, $\|x\| \leq \sup\{|x^*(x)|: x^* \in M, \|x^*\| \leq c\}$.
3. There is a positive constant $c$ such that if $x^* \in \text{ball } X^*$, there is a sequence $\{x_k^*\}$ in $M$, $\|x_k^*\| \leq c$, such that $x_k^* \to x^*$ in the weak* topology.

**Attempt:** I thought the statement is true without any extra conditions because as far I am aware, the weak* closure of $M$ is the set of all weak* limits of sequences in $M$ by definition. But this is an exercise from Conway's functional analysis book, so this cannot be so simple.

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it isn't by definition.  You need to go through metrizability of weak*-topology on $B^*$ (the unit ball of $X^*$) for separable Banach space $X$ to get $X^*$ (with the weak*-topology) is sequential.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand. What is $B^*$? I assume you mean unit ball of $X^*$.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the metrizability argument you mentioned?